# Catch Out Of Memory Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I wrote a java class to create me a custom layout in Android. With little data is working correctly, the problem is when I try to upload a lot of data in the layout.

I explain a bit the structure of the layout:
is a table where I insert data that I previously downloaded via REST query.
The exception is in their class:

```
public class TableMainLayout  extends RelativeLayout {}
```

**How can I handle this exception? and maybe go back to the Activity prior with a nice allert?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this by implementing the [onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory%28%29) callback.

Comment: Ok but when i call it ?

Comment: It's a callback, you don't call it, the system calls it for you, you just have to override this function in your activity or fragment class, for example, and act accordingly there.

Comment: You do not call it, the system calls it when it gets into a low memory state. However, `onLowMemory()` is not that reliable that it will be called. It's just a best effort method.

Comment: I call this class / layout in an action bar. And when this call is in a try / Catch but can not find the exception class